# how to bind multiple Node in RadTreeView

Tags: c#

**Question:**

How do i bind multiple Nodes in RadTreeView

This is my code:

```
if (lblCategory != null && lblCategory.Text != string.Empty && rtCategory != null)
 {
     string[] tree = lblCategory.Text.Split(',');

     for (int i = 0; i < tree.Length; i++)
     {                      
         foreach (RadTreeNode t in rtCategory.Nodes)
         {                           
             if (t.Value == tree[i])
             {
                 t.Selected = true;
             }
         }

     }
         rtCategory.ExpandAllNodes();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if (lblCategory != null && lblCategory.Text != string.Empty && rtCategory != null)
                {
                    string[] tree = lblCategory.Text.Split(',');

```
                for (int i = 0; i < tree.Length; i++)
                {

                    foreach (RadTreeNode t in rtCategory.GetAllNodes())
                    {                           
                        if (t.Value == tree[i])
                        {
                            t.Selected = true;
                        }
                    }

                }
                rtCategory.ExpandAllNodes();
            }
```

Use GetAllNodes() instead of Node in foreach condition